# zsh custom function breaks

Tags: git, shell, zsh

I'm new to zsh and struggling with this simplest function which worked perfectly for me in bash. I'm adding it to .zshrc file.

```
function gcp {
    git add .
    git commit -am "$@"
    git push
}
```

But when I call it, I get:

```
gcp "Update mac deps"
fatal: bad revision 'Update mac deps'
```

UPD: uhhh that's because of for some reason:

```
which gcp
gcp: aliased to git cherry-pick
```

UPD2: okay, the problem was that oh-my-zsh ships with a ton of built-in git aliases, so the solution - I just had comment out `gcp` one from `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh`.

Comment: This is why I find things like `oh-my-zsh` more trouble than they are worth. Unless you carefully read the full configuration, you don't actually know how your shell is configured. I prefer to treat its configuration as something to look through and pick out the pieces you find useful to add to your *own* configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a commit in your Clone has not been updated.
Please `git pull origin/master` it out and then `git checkout <branch>` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, the problem was that `oh-my-zsh` ships with a ton of built-in git aliases, so the solution - I just had comment out `gcp` one from `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/git/git.plugin.zsh`.